# In MS-Access, how to display the old foreign key in a combo box when the foreign key no longer exists?

Tags: forms, ms-access, combobox

I have a combobox with two columns.  The first column is hidden.  The second is not hidden.  The first column is the bound column.  The second is the display text.

```
ColumnCount = 1
ColumnWidths = 0";1"
RowSource = "a select statement"
BoundColumn = 1
```

For example:

```
SKU       | Description
"teapot"  | "Pretty Teapots"
"saucer"  | "Excellent Saucers"
"tallcup" | "Tall Cups"
```

The user sees the second column in the combo box. Everything works. If the user chooses "Tall Cups", then "tallcup" is stored in the underlying table.

Later....
The value "tallcup" is removed from the list on purpose.  What I now want is for the user to see "tallcup" in the Combo Box for those records where it was originally set.  But for new records, "tallcup" is not an option.

What it currently shows is blank.  It's as if nothing was ever selected.

Do I need to do something with the `format` property?

Here are some related links that I found around the internet, but they didn't help me much:

http://www.tutcity.com/access/display-the-corresponding-unbound-column-entry-of-a-combobox.79599.html

https://www.google.com/search?q=ms-access+2+column+show+first+combobox+missing+show+anyway&rls=com.microsoft%3Aen-us%3AIE-SearchBox&oe=&gws_rd=ssl&oq=&gs_l=

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/MS_Access/A_5890-Adding-the-option-all-to-a-ComboBox.html

Comment: When you say removed on purpose what exactly do you mean? Do you not want it as an option for new records, but for old records you want the data, but changing then will mean that you have to not have the option anymore?

Comment: Exactly.  I do not want it as an option for new records, but for old records, I want the data, but changing them will mean I will not have the option anymore.

Comment: I had the idea of using the Active flag as suggested by Gustav.

Answer (score 0):

Add a third coloumn with an Active flag. Set it to False for tallcup and add an beforeupdate event setting Cancel to Not Active and pop a message if so.

Comment: I would prefer a different solution than this.  I wish to not have the data anymore in the child table.

Comment: You cannot both have the value and not have the value. That's essentially what you ask for.

Comment: It works if I bind and display column 1.  It doesn't work when this involves two columns.

Comment: I don't follow ... you can bind one or none coloumn but have (and display) as many as you want.